# Which ubuntu version to install

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox

I am a new user of Ubuntu, I've been only using windows my whole life, but recently i needed to install Ubuntu, so I could use some bioinformatics software only available for the Linux operating systems.

I tried using VirtualBox, but it's painfully slow and won't allow me to run all the software that I would need for DNA sequence analysis.

**My question is:**
Will it be best to install Ubuntu inside windows, I mean by running the Ubuntu installer programme within windows, or should I just install it next to windows on it's own partition?

Will this last option slow my computer's performance while using windows?
And which Ubuntu version would be best for my PC?

My system information:

- RAM 4G
- CPU 32-bit 2.40GHz

Comment: You might consider using [Ubuntu on Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-ubuntu-on-windows#0)

Comment: The following link and links from it may help you, [How to select the version and flavour of Ubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865)

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of options for you. 
First of all, there won't be a noticeable difference between setting up a dual boot system with Windows and Linux or just erasing Windows. Only one is running at a time, so you shouldn't have a problem. If you want to keep Windows and you have the hard disk space, go ahead and install Linux on its own partition (as long as you're willing to do the work and the research to get the partitioning right).

Otherwise, go ahead and install Linux on its own. It's the easiest and the quickest path.

As for which distribution you might like, that's a common linux question. 
You'll want something fast and lightweight, but not too difficult to use. Ubuntu is great for beginners, so you seem to be on the right track.

Because you're so familiar with Windows, I would definitely suggest Lubuntu: 
https://lubuntu.net

Xubuntu is a close second, however: https://xubuntu.org

You can try either one by using a live bootable USB. That way you can get a feel for them before making the decision. Make sure to get the appropriate 32-bit isos though.

Answer (score 2):

LUBUNTU (lightweight, fast, easier) https://lubuntu.net/

### About lubuntu

lubuntu is a fast and lightweight operating system with a clean and easy-to-use user interface. It is a Linux system, that uses the **minimal desktop LXDE**, and a selection of light applications. Because of this, **Lubuntu has very low hardware requirements**.

### System Requirements

Our tests show that until version 14.10 lubuntu can be installed on a Pentium II or Celeron system with 256 MB RAM to get a usable system. With 512 MB of RAM, you do not need to worry much. The recommended "lubuntu Desktop" **from version 15.04 onwards is 1 GB of RAM**. For Internet services like Facebook, Youtube, and Google Docs about 1 GB RAM are needed. For local programs like Libre Office and simple browsing habits 512 MB RAM are usually sufficient. For PCs with less resources, there are alternative lubuntu installers on the download pages, that provide a basic running system for those systems.

More information is here: https://docs.lubuntu.net/